# TFS 2017 get notified on build quality change

Tags: build, notifications

Perhaps this is a question specific to non-English installations, since my UI is half-German half-English.

Also, the "Qualität" field starts out as "Quality", but this is also disallowed when clicking on "Save".

I am getting "Index was outside the bounds of the array" on "Save".

[image]

How can I configure notifications on build quality change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be an issue for TFS 2017. I have submitted a feedback for this issue You can track it here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/73811/error-message-index-was-outside-the-bounds-of-the.html

As a workaround you can **change your user profile locale to English**,then you can save and use the notification.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, that did the trick! I thought I had tried that, but perhaps not properly refreshed the browser afterwards.